# Using Symbol.iterator to access iterator of ProxyObject

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

I have created a Java class that implements the Graal ProxyObject interface. I can access all methods and properties of that class via `hasMember(String key)` and `getMember(String key)` methods. But if I use something like

```
myObject[Symbol.iterator]();
```

I get an exception:

```
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: myObject[(intermediate value).iterator] is not a function
```

The problem is that myObject[Symbol.iterator] returns undefined.
How can I access a member of my proxy object via Symbol...?

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible on the Java side. The Polyglot Interop protocol only accepts `String` keys (see e.g. the `getMember(String key)` you quote above), but `Symbol.iterator` is a JavaScript `Symbol`. You need to somehow special-case that. It depends on what your ProxyObject does - does it delegate to a JavaScript object in the end that DOES understand what `Symbol.iterator` is? Then you could pass in some magic string and delegate appropriately.

The current JavaScript interop code always returns `undefined` for the pattern `interopObject[Symbol]`. You need to catch that situation even before you call `myObject[Symbol.iterator]`, as this would never reach your `ProxyObject`.

```
//sketch of a solution on the JavaScript side
function read(obj, key) {
  if (key instanceof Symbol) {
    return obj[key.toString()]; //resulting in e.g. "Symbol(Symbol.iterator)"
  } else {
    return obj[key];
  }
}

//Java ProxyObject implementation: special-case the key "Symbol(Symbol.iterator)"
```

Best,
Christian

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that would be the case. Since I don't have any influence on the JS that is executed. Do you know if there is any way to proxy every access to a js object property? I was thinking of writing a proxy for 'get' in object prototype but with out any luck.

Comment: You can return a `Symbol` from JavaScript code to `Java`. You can store it in a `Value`, and you can pass that value back to JavaScript. So you can do something along these lines: `Value result = jsContext.eval("js", "(function (o,k) { return o[k]; });").execute(myObj,mySymbol);` and pass in your pure JavaScript object (not a proxy of it) and the symbol to access that value.

Answer (score 0):

It took some time but I solved it myself, based on the idea of Christians answer. The library [sj4js](https://www.visions-tec.de/s/dev#others) handles the use of `Symbol.*` and also calls the appropriate methods of an object. Here an example for an Array.

```
JsArray hm = new JsArray("a","b","c");
        
try (JScriptEngine engine = new JScriptEngine()) {
    engine.addObject("test", hm);
            
    engine.exec("console.log([...test]);");
    // output a,b,c
}
```